# strange behaviour of chrome (31.0.1650.57 m)

Tags: google-chrome, cross-browser

I just show you my screenshot with small comment on it, and ask: what is it? (in other browsers all works fine).

http://s019.radikal.ru/i603/1311/b3/b1d2848ae340.jpg

computed style of **li**

```
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
direction: ltr;
display: inline-block;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-size: 13px;
height: 54px;
line-height: 18px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: none;
margin-bottom: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
margin-right: 10px;
margin-top: 0px;
overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: hidden;
text-align: left;
width: 54px;
font-family:'Open Sans';
```

computed style of **ul**

```
border-bottom-left-radius: 0px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 0px;
box-sizing: border-box;
color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
direction: ltr;
display: block;
font-family: 'Open Sans';
font-size: 13px;
height: 116px;
line-height: 18px;
list-style-image: none;
list-style-position: outside;
list-style-type: none;
margin-bottom: 10px;
margin-top: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
width: 350px;
```

Comment: Any resolution, facing the same issue. And its a bit random.